# Java Properties Files in a Foreign Language

Tags: java

What would be the correct format of the strings in a properties for say, Japanese, unicode or HTML encoded?

For example, which of these is correct to use?

```
title=&#12497;&#12540;&#12488;&#12490;&#12540;
```

(the above displays as パートナー)

```
title=\u30D1\u30FC\u30C8\u30CA\u30FC
```

What would the most likely output of someone creating a translation for these strings, that is when they type it on their keyboard?

The second style doesn't generate the correct Japanese characters in the browser, so how do I deal with it, if that is a preferred style?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The native properties loader uses the "ISO 8859-1" encoding as specified in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29).

The strings having unicode escapes aren't unescaped, so they're not really usable for direct usage.

I suggest you use a specific loader like [this one](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~imaman/programs/unicodeprops.html) so you can handle unicode (for example UTF-8).

Comment: I am currently using ResourceBundle so I can support property files for different locales.